# Change start of the week in Date Picker

Tags: config, datetime

A simple question with hopefully a simple answer.

How can I make the date picker in the admin area start the week (i.e. each new line) with Mondays rather than Sundays?

I'm sure it will just be a configuration issue. I just can't see where to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently this isn’t configurable, but I suppose it should be. I’ll add it to the list, and update this answer when it’s possible.

**Update:**

As of [Craft 2.3](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates/2.3), each user can choose their own preferred week start day from their account settings.

Comment: Have ticked it as answered for now - but looking forward to having it added. Thanks

Comment: It's now possible with Craft 2.3, @mattl!

Comment: Boom! You guys are the best.